# how to load tinyMCE by javascript for dynamically created textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

var newDiv = document.createElement('span');

```
 newDiv.setAttribute("id", "optionCount" + currentOptionCount);
 document.getElementById('more3').appendChild(newDiv);

            var strToAdd=""  ;
            strToAdd =strToAdd + currentOptionCount+')';
            strToAdd = strToAdd + '<input type="radio" name="rightanswer" value="'+currentOptionCount+'"/>';
            strToAdd = strToAdd + '<br/>';
            strToAdd = strToAdd + '<textarea class="tinymce-enabled" name="multians'+currentOptionCount+'" cols="60" rows="6"></textarea>';
            alert("multians"+currentOptionCount);
            strToAdd = strToAdd + '<br/>';
            strToAdd =strToAdd + '</span>';

         newDiv.innerHTML=strToAdd;

         $('#more3').append(newDiv);


 //   tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand('mceAddEditor', true, "multians"+currentOptionCount);
  tinyMCE.EditorManager.execCommand('mceAddControl', true, "multians"+currentOptionCount);
```

//     tinyMCE.init();

The above javascript code creates a textarea dynamically. Already exist static textarea are comming with menu of tinyMCE but this dynamically created textareas are generated as a normal textarea.

So please suggest whats the mistake i am making.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: With TinyMCE v4 you should use `mceAddEditor` because `mceAddControl` was the name in v3

Comment: Sir, i tried both the name but result is same.#jerome

Answer (score 0):

I made a small change you to your code and posted it to TinyMCE Fiddle:

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/3Dfaab

This loads TinyMCE into the dynamically created `<textarea>`.

Effectively your last line was not right - I used `tinymce.init({})` instead but the end result is the same.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir for ur effort. And it works too But not helpful for me as of now, bcoz i am using customized tinyMCE i.e pramukh type pad in order to provide native indian language supported editor. 
With little change to ur code, the editor is coming but the pull down menu of the editor are coming at top of the page, which is not good so don't know what to do ...